# Is there any protection from RAM corrupt in file copy routines (in Windows)?

Tags: windows, memory, file-transfer, file-corruption, memory-management

Recently I found one of my memory stick has bad bytes. Before that I was suspecting different hardware and reinstalled Windows and copyied my files from one disk to another.

Is there a chance, that many of my files got corrupted if copying buffer was occasionally overlaying with bad memory area?

Or there is some protecton from this in Windows?

**UPDATE**

I had system crashes, reporting memory corrupt. I had Windows memory test seeing no errors (or may be error was not permanent), but free version of MemTest86 shown memory errors in simple Test #3.

Comment: From what little I know of the actual tech underlying it... non-ECC RAM will crash if it hits a bad area; ECC RAM will self-correct & continue to run, copying correctly. So, my best guess [which I'm not going to post as an answer] is that if it didn't crash, or you have ECC [server mobos & Macs, usually], then the data should be fine.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Nope... non-ECC RAM will cause data corruption, and certain type of data corruption (but by no means all) will cause a crash.  I/O bounce buffers used for file copy would be very unlikely to cause a crash.  (Examples of corruption that could cause a crash would be in areas being executed as code or containing pointer variables)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On consumer desktop systems, no. There is no detection of corrupt memory data, as long as the incorrect data is successfully retrieved. I know that sounds contradictory, but it is entirely possible. The memory controller treats data like a black box - it doesn't know or care what the data is, it simply obeys the protocol for completing the transfers in and out of DRAM. If the protocol is obeyed and data is successfully stored in the DRAM *and* there are no protocol violations when the data is retrieved, then the memory controller has no idea anything went wrong in the DRAM. It doesn't check the contents to ensure it is the same as when it was stored. The OS doesn't do this either. The blue screen of death is only thrown at the user if there is a *protocol violation* during a memory transfer, or if you are unlucky enough to have OS code/data corrupted by the bad DRAM. It is important to remember though, that even in the second case, the BSOD was not caused by any mechanism intentionally detecting errors. Your OS is a big program like any other, so if its executing code or data is corrupted, it may try to execute invalid instructions, access data it doesn't own, or any number of other illegal actions that the OS *does* detect and crash as a result.

An exception to this is memory that supports [Error Correcting Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECC_memory). These are little checksums that are stored along with the data in a DRAM (or other memory device). They are used by the memory controller to ensure the integrity of the data itself. This memory is more expensive and generally only found in servers. Windows has a [pretty sophisticated system](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/whea/how-whea-performs-pfa-on-ecc-memory) for handling ECC errors (since they are not necessarily fatal) but without ECC memory, there is no way to detect data corruption as long as the [JEDEC spec for DRAM data transfers](https://www.jedec.org/category/technology-focus-area/main-memory-ddr3-ddr4-sdram) is obeyed.

However, this does not mean that all is lost. There is no live checking for corrupt memory, but if you get the BSOD due to a memory issue, Windows *can* detect this and it will schedule an automatic run of the [Windows Memory Diagnostic utility](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700221.aspx), which can help pinpoint memory errors. You can also run it manually when you suspect you have bad memory that is corrupting your data.

Comment: You make it sound like there are only two kinds of memory: stupid and ECC.   Is there really no [*error-**detecting***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_detection_and_correction#Error_detection_schemes) memory?   There are various techniques, like parity bits and simple checksums, that would allow hardware to *realize* (detect) that an error had occurred, without being able to fix (correct) it.   I’m not saying that you’re wrong — I simply don’t know — but, if you are correct, IMNSHO, the industry is allowing the existence of a major vacuum in the market.

Comment: @Scott Yes, when it comes to error handling, that is what I'm saying. The vacuum is allowed because that's what the market wants. Every single transistor costs money, time, and resources to design, validate, and market. The industry has found that the current rate of errors (very low) and methods to handle them (BSOD) are "good enough", and that the increased cost of implementing error detection in consumer memory is not worth the cost. It's not ideal, but it is good enough for consumer devices, especially when ECC memory *is* available for people who have higher data integrity requirements.

Comment: @Scott I have to amend my previous comment: I just found this [manufacturer](http://www.intelligentmemory.com/ECC-DRAM/) that apparently sells DIMMs with ECC capability built in, so they can be used with systems that don't support ECC memory. You may be able to find smaller manufacturers that add parity or other checking on the DIMM, but my first comment still applies to most of the industry. Also note that parity and other simple checkers *are* frequently used on command and address pins, or other internal signals. It's just rare to find them used for the data itself, outside of ECC RAM.